# Paperclip error in rails - uploaded file can't be empty file name can't be blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I'm attempting to upload a pdf file using paperclip to a rails application. I'm able to get the form up to upload the element, however when I go to submit, I get the following errors:

```
2 errors prohibited this asset from being saved: Uploaded file can't
be empty Uploaded file file name can't be empty
```

Relevant code:

Model:

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base    
  belongs_to :course

  #set up "uploaded_file" field as attached_file (using Paperclip) 
  has_attached_file :uploaded_file
  validates_attachment_size :uploaded_file, :less_than => 20.megabytes         
  validates_attachment_presence :uploaded_file 
end
```

Controller:

```
class AssetsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_asset, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  respond_to :html

  def index
    @assets = Assets.all
    respond_with(@assets)
  end

  def show
    respond_with(@asset)
  end

  def new
    @asset = Asset.new
    respond_with(@asset)
  end

  def edit
    @asset = Assets.find(:params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @asset = Asset.new(asset_params)
    @asset.save
    respond_with(@asset)
  end

  def update
    @asset = Assets.find(params[:id])
    @asset.update(asset_params)
    respond_with(@asset)
  end

  def destroy
    @asset = Assets.find(params[:id])
    @asset.destroy
    respond_with(@asset)
  end

  private
    def set_asset
      @asset = Asset.find(params[:id])
    end

    def asset_params
      params.require(:asset).permit(:course_id, :uploaded_file)
    end
end
```

view:

```
<%= form_for(@asset) do |f| %>
  <% if @asset.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@asset.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this asset from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @asset.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :course_id %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :course_id %>
  </div>
      <p> 
        <%= f.label :uploaded_file, "File" %><br /> 
        <%= f.file_field :uploaded_file %> 
      </p>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add `multipart: true` to your form definition:

```
<%= form_for(@asset, multipart: true) do |f| %>
```